# Why does PHPUnit take so long to register my code changes?

Tags: php, phpunit, command-line-interface

I'm starting to study PHPUnit, and I've noticed that when I alter my code (eg. to fix an error) PHPUnit continues to complain about the error unless I stop and sit with my hands off the keyboard for 30 seconds or so. Why does this happen and what can I do to stop it? I'm using the default `php.ini` value of `opcache.enable_cli=0`, but as I'm new to both PHPUnit and command-line PHP I have no idea where else to look.

EDIT: I am using Bluefish to edit; the machine in question is running Ubuntu 18.04.5 with ext4 filesystem; the working directory is ext4 on a NAS NFS mount. I've been using this setup for several months with other languages and not noticed the problem until now.

Comment: Your IDE/editor and/or filesystem is most likely to blame here.

Comment: It's possible, but (as I mention above) I've been using this setup for several months working with Python, HTML and JavaScript with no problem until now.

Comment: How do you start phpunit? From within Bluefeet? And please re-create the scenario not on NFS. Does it behave the same?

Comment: Some further experimentation leads me to believe it's an NFS latency issue, due to the fact that I'm editing on one machine, running on a second one and storing on a third. Should I delete this post, or is it worth posting an answer?